# nested query & transaction

Tags: mysql, subquery

**Update #1:** query gives me syntax error on Left Join line (running the query within the left join independently works perfectly though)

```
SELECT b1.company_id, ((sum(b1.credit)-sum(b1.debit)) as 'Balance'

FROM MyTable b1
JOIN CustomerInfoTable c on c.id = b1.company_id

#Filter for Clients of particular brand, package and active status
where c.brand_id = 2 and c.status = 2 and c.package_id = 3

LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT b2.company_id, sum(b2.debit) as 'Current_Usage'
  FROM MyTable b2
  WHERE year(b2.timestamp) = '2012' and month(b2.timestamp) = '06'
  GROUP BY b2.company_id
)
b3 on b3.company_id = b1.company_id
group by b1.company_id;
```

**Original Post:**

I keep track of debits and credits in the same table. The table has the following schema:

```
| company_id | timestamp | credit | debit |
| 10 | MAY-25 | 100 | 000 |
| 11 | MAY-25 | 000 | 054 |
| 10 | MAY-28 | 000 | 040 |
| 12 | JUN-01 | 100 | 000 |
| 10 | JUN-25 | 150 | 000 |
| 10 | JUN-25 | 000 | 025 |
```

As my result, I want to to see:

```
| Grouped by: company_id | Balance* | Current_Usage (in June) |
| 10 | 185 | 25 |
| 12 | 100 | 0 |
| 11 | -54 | 0 |
```

**Balance:** Calculated by (sum(credit) - sum(debits))* - timestamp does not matter

**Current_Usage:** Calculated by sum(debits) - but *only* for debits in JUN.

The problem: If I filter by JUN timestamp right away, it does not calculate the balance of all time but only the balance of any transactions in June.

How can I calculate the current usage by month but the balance on all transactions in the table. I have everything working, except that it filters only the JUN results into the current usage calculation in my code:

```
SELECT b.company_id, ((sum(b.credit)-sum(b.debit))/1024/1024/1024/1024) as 'BW_remaining', sum(b.debit/1024/1024/1024/1024/28*30) as 'Usage_per_month'

FROM mytable b

#How to filter this only for the current_usage calculation?
WHERE month(a.timestamp) = 'JUN' and a.credit = 0


#Group by company in order to sum all entries for balance
group by b.company_id
order by b.balance desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

what you will need here is a join with sub query which will filter based on month.

```
SELECT T1.company_id, 
       ((sum(T1.credit)-sum(T1.debit))/1024/1024/1024/1024) as 'BW_remaining', 
       MAX(T3.DEBIT_PER_MONTH)
FROM MYTABLE T1
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT T2.company_id, SUM(T2.debit) T3.DEBIT_PER_MONTH
  FROM MYTABLE T2
  WHERE month(T2.timestamp) = 'JUN'
  GROUP BY T2.company_id
)
T3 ON T1.company_id-T3.company_id
GROUP BY T1.company_id
```

I havn't tested the query. The point here i am trying to make is how you can join your existing query to get usage per month.

Comment: I get a syntax error on the left join. If I run just the query within the join, it goes through fine:

I run the following query:

###update: It's really difficult to format code in the comment so I updated the question with the code under Update #1

Answer (score 0):

alright, thanks to @Kshitij I got it working. In case somebody else is running into the same issue, this is how I solved it:

```
SELECT b1.company_id, ((sum(b1.credit)-sum(b1.debit)) as 'Balance',
  (
  SELECT sum(b2.debit)
  FROM MYTABLE b2
  WHERE b2.company_id = b1.company_id and year(b2.timestamp) = '2012' and month(b2.timestamp) = '06'
  GROUP BY b2.company_id
  ) AS 'Usage_June'

FROM MYTABLE b1

#Group by company in order to add sum of all zones the company is using
group by b1.company_id
order by Usage_June desc;
```